# The dd command isn't appear to accomplish anything

Tags: usb, dd, burning

I'm currently trying to burn the Ubuntu operating system onto a USB flash drive of mine, so I can boot onto Ubuntu with my Chromebook. In order to do this, I executed the following `dd` command:

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sda1
```

So far, this has been running for 18 hours, and it's appeared have done nothing, except produce the following output:

> ```
> 0+0 records in
> 0+0 records out
> 0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.01807 s, 0.0 kB/s
> ```

Is this a normal behavior for the `dd` command? Have I done something wrong?

To clarify, I'm running this command on a Raspberry Pi, running Debian.

Comment: Are you *sure* that `/dev/sda1` is your USB stick?

Comment: why do you think it has been running for 18 hours?

Comment: @roaima Positively. I ran `lsblk` and it listed `/dev/sda1` with the name of my USB stick.

Comment: @mikeserv me? I would be worried that writing to `/dev/sda` had broken enough of the filesystem that the ISO no longer appeared to be only 4GB. I would have also not used the default blocksize for `dd` but either increased it to 32M or (better still) used `cat`. But that's me.

Comment: @roaima - that was a comment for the asker. I said that because the output above suggests it stopped, and did so in .02 seconds.

Comment: @mikeserv ah gotcha

Comment: it appears to me that you named your `if=` incorrectly. Are you sure that file exists where you think it does? And are you certain it is not *empty*?

Comment: @mikeserv I've named it correctly. I did discover that somehow the disc image was completely empty afterwards though. I'm now getting new errors, but that's a different issue.

Comment: well, there you go. `dd` did exactly what you asked it to and copied 0 bytes over `/dev/sda1` - you just truncated that partition in .02 seconds.

Comment: @roaima - a 32M `dd` blocksize is almost definitely going to be slower than a 512byte blocksize. half of a system page is usually about ideal. `dd` has to copy its input block in to memory then out to output. telling it to spend so much copying input to RAM is not any better than telling it to spend all of its time doing `read()` and `write()`. Basically you should try to synchronize it so that by the time a `read()` is completed it is instantly ready to `write()` and vice-versa, rather than waiting on context switches and/or memory allocations.

Comment: @mikeserv empirically I have found that the larger blocksize is beneficial. It appears to be related to the number of syscalls involved (fewer syscalls with larger buffers runs far faster than many syscalls with small buffers).

Comment: @roaima - well, i think you should try it again. im not saying that the 512 byte blocksize is ideal - it's *also* slow. but bigger is not necessarily better - there is a bell curve to the performance versus blocksize ratio, and 32M is *way* on the far right side of it.

Comment: @mikeserv I'll certainly revisit it next time I'm going to need `dd` for any non-trivial operation.

Comment: `dd` is saying that the INPUT file is empty — it reports successfully copying all 0 bytes of it. Check `ls -l ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so turns out that my Ubuntu disk image had somehow been completely destroyed, and was empty. I simply had thought it hadn't stopped and had kept executing simply because it didn't return to a prompt like this:

> ```
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $
> ```

Comment: Sorry to hear you've lost your disk. I do still think that `/dev/sda` was your disk, and something like `/dev/sdb` would have been your removable stick.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use the whole drive, not only the first partition:

`sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sda`

You can get the progress of dd by runnung in a second terminal:

```
sudo kill -USR1 $(pidof dd)
```

The progress is shown in the first terminal.

Are you sure that /dev/sda is right?
This is normaly the first device, the built-in harddrive.

Comment: Why the downvote without comment? This seems a perfectly reasonable answer

Comment: @roaima - no, it isn't. whether or not a partition device or a root device is selected is irrelevant to the `0 bytes` issue, and you don't actually *have* to use the whole disk anyway. Also, I don't think the chromebook's `dd` will handle USR1 as a GNU `dd` does - that behavior is strictly contrary to spec, actually, and that will likely have an opposite effect to the desired one.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know he's using Chremebooks dd, so have a look at the man page (if something like that exists) or use linux on another PC.

Comment: @user137926 I'm not running the command on a Chromebook. See my edit.

Comment: So, did my answer work?

Comment: This question answers how to see `dd` status.  This also mentions best practice for a typical installation of using the device identifier, vs an individual partition.

Answer (score 2):

### Use pipeviewer to see transfer totals/rate.

1. `sudo apt-get install pv`
2. `dd if=ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso |pv | sudo dd of=/dev/sda1`

This will show you the current speed, as well as the total transfer for `dd`.  You can specify the filesize and get an ETA and percentage complete by using `pv -s 700m`, for example.