# The dd command fails with an "Input/output" error while burning a USB stick

Tags: usb, dd, burning

This question is somewhat related to the previous question I asked regarding the `dd` command, [The dd command isn't appear to accomplish anything](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235262/the-dd-command-isnt-appear-to-accomplish-anything/235268#235268).

I'm trying to burn the Ubuntu operating system onto a USB flash drive, so that I can boot from it. Currently I'm getting this output like this when I attempt the burn:

> ```
> dd: reading `ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso': Input/output error
> 1280+0 records in
> 1280+0 records out
> 655360 bytes (655 kB) copied, 0.04214 s, xx.x MB/s
> ```

For reference, I'm running the following command:

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso of=/dev/sda1
```

To clarify:

- I know that `/dev/sda1` is my USB stick.
- I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi, running the Debian distribution.

Comment: Can you read the SD card?  That is `sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null`.

Comment: is the iso located on `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: @Brian Yes, I can read the USB drive.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes it is. When I run the `lsblk` it tells me that it's the case.

Comment: /dev/sda1 is a partition, not a drive.  Or at least, it should be.  What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` print?

Comment: well obviously you cant overwrite the partition with the file that exists on the partition.

Comment: @TheSidhekin http://pastebin.com/S7V8RBzq

Comment: Yup; /dev/sda1 is the first (and only) partition on /dev/sda – which presumably is your USB drive.  Unless they've started making ISOs for partitions (pretty sure they haven't, and pretty sure you wouldn't be able to boot from one), you should use `of=/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that I really don't understand a lot of basic concepts about this stuff. Turns out I was trying to burn the Ubuntu disk image, *while* it was contained inside of my USB flash drive. All I had to do was move the file to a different location, `cd` there, and continue with the `dd` command.